# How to get list of all the versions and labels applied for a particular file in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I have a file

```
"N:\E123_view\ABC\XYZ\data.doc"
```

I want to get all the versions of the file and all the labels tagged to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, in command line, is to use a version tree: [`cleartool lsvtree`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm).

```
cd N:\E123_view\ABC\XYZ
cleartool lsvtree -all data.doc > afile.txt
```

> lists all versions on a branch, not the selected versions only; annotates each version with all of its version labels.

Another approach is to use [`lshistory`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-25&lang=en) combined with [`fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-6-6)

```
cleartool lshistory -fmt "%n %l\n" data.doc
```

- `%n` will print the version, as in `/main/rel2_bugfix/1`
- `%l` will print the label (if present).